# PHP Email Form/server Issue?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, server

For some reason My PHP email form does not send the html form data, the headings are there, but the imputed data is not however when the files are put on the development server, a sub domain of the main website 123.123.com, the email sends with the form data, with no issue at all.

It seems to do this on all the forms on the website, could this be server related? or am I missing something. any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

 mail( "Test@test.con, "Interlinks Sign Up", 
"\nName: - $fulllname
\nEmail:- $email
\nContact Number: - $contactnumber
\nCountry:- $country
\nTown/City:- $city
\nPost Code:- $postcode
\nAbout Yourself: - $about
\nWork And Business: - $work
\nJob Description: - $job
\nIndustry Description: - $industry
\nWebsite: - $website
\nLanguage: - $language
\nWho To Meet:- $meet
\nAgree: - $agree ",        
"From: blank@test.com" );
```

?>

Comment: Where are those variables supposed to come from? (*Who dares saying register_globals…*)

Comment: You're probably missing something. With just one line of code it's going to be difficult to work out what.

Comment: I can assure you that they link to a html file and the forms work on the development server.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the data from your HTML form you will need to use `$_POST['form_element_name_here']` or `$_GET['form_element_name_here']` depending on the type of form action that you used. If you are already doing thing and are binding these to the variables that you are using in your original code we will need to have a look at the entire PHP script and HTML front end that is processing the form.

Comment: I sadly can not post the HTML due to the size, here is teh address though maybe you can inspect the code, http://121businessnetwork.com/Interlinks/Visitor/Pages/signup.html

Comment: Ok, can I see the entirety of the PHP code then?